# How to get tkinter messagebox to appear in front of toplevel

Tags: tkinter

I'm writing a program with Python 3 and tkinter in which toplevels initially appear centered in the root window. If a toplevel isn't moved out of the way, it covers up any messagebox that may arise to display an error message. The messagebox appears in front of the root window, but behind the toplevel. Simple example from the command line to show what happens:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> from tkinter import messagebox
>>> root = Tk()
>>> texto = Toplevel(root) # (Manually put toplevel in front of root)
>>> messagebox.showinfo(message='Does this work?')
```

Is there a way to get the messagebox to appear in front of the toplevel?

Comment: works as expected on my mac, what OS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried making the messagebox a child of the toplevel?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 17.3. I wasn't sure how to make the messagebox a child of the toplevel. I tried this, but it didn't work: `>>> mess = messagebox.showinfo(texto, message='Does this work?')` The messagebox still appeared underneath the toplevel.

Comment: `messagebox.showinfo("title", "message",master=texto)` would be how you specify it as a child of `texto`

Comment: Slightly modified (`messagebox.showinfo(message='Does this work'), master=texto)`, it does work! Just turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it. :o)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of master I tried by using: "parent" as this one [Messagebox with top level as Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910866/python-3-tkinter-messagebox-with-a-toplevel-as-master)
and it worked for me!

```
messagebox.showinfo("title", "message",parent=texto)
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10, using master=texto does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just define the parent of messagebox

```
messagebox.showinfo(parent=textto, message="blah")
```