# Is there a method to create a messagebox in top-level in tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, toplevel, tkmessagebox

This code opens a message box on the first window. But I want to open the message box on the second window.

```
    From tkinter import * 
    From tkinter import messagebox as m
    Def b():
        A=m.askquestion (" question ","really want to go back")
        if(A=1):
            R2.destroy()
    Def a():
        global R2
        R2=Toplevel()
        Label(R2,text='This is second window').pack()

        Button(R2 ,text='back',command=b).pack()
    Def c():
        global Root
        Root=Tk()
        Button(root, text='next',command=a).pack()
    c()
```

---

I'm looking for any suggestions about how to open the message box on the second window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 Tkinter - Messagebox with a toplevel as master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910866/python-3-tkinter-messagebox-with-a-toplevel-as-master)

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution very easy: you have to give the parent to messagebox:

```
    From tkinter import * 
    From tkinter import messagebox as m
    Def b():
        A=m.askquestion (" question ","really want to go back", parent = R2)
        if(A=1):
            R2.destroy()
    Def a():
        global R2
        R2=Toplevel()
        Label(R2,text='This is second window').pack()

        Button(R2 ,text='back',command=b).pack()
    Def c():
        global Root
        Root=Tk()
        Button(root, text='next',command=a).pack()
    c()
```